# music21 seems to modify MIDI file when reading/rewritting it

Tags: python, midi, music21

I've got a midi file from the [Groove MIDI dataset](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/groove). Here is an example: [groove/drummer1/eval_session/1_funk-groove1_138_beat_4-4.mid](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xcWT8Uodgh1TG9QxZfMUYul1bUAu54C4/view?usp=drive_link).

I'm using music21 to manipulate the midi file, but it seems that it does not read/write properly the file. Here is a quick experiment to show that:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import music21

file_path = Path("groove/drummer1/eval_session/1_funk-groove1_138_beat_4-4.mid")

stream = music21.converter.parse(file_path, quantizePost=False)
stream.write("midi", fp="/tmp/test_write.mid")
```

So I am basically reading the file from disk, and then immediately rewriting it. But when I open the two files in a MIDI editor, they are different:
[image: Two pianorolls side by side]

Am I doing something wrong? The files I'm dealing with are drums tracks, maybe there is something different to do in that case?

Versions:

- Python: 3.11.5
- Music21: 9.1.0

Comment: Just guessing, but the mapping is not exactly the same than General Midi (https://magenta.tensorflow.org/datasets/groove#drum-mapping)

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that it should make a difference. If a note has the pitch 39 in the input midi file (whatever drum 39 corresponds to), I expect that the output file will have this note with the pitch 39.